# Can you script the MDS database upgrade after SQL Patch applied

Tags: sql-server, automation, master-data-services

I have recently automated the SQL patching of ~200 development servers.

Currently we have 6 servers that run the Microsoft Master Data Services feature.

After a SQL patch is applied there is a manual step to go in and open Master Data Services Configuration Manager and do an upgrade of the schema.

Since this kills my automation for those 6 servers I am trying to find out if there is a programmatic way to run this upgrade process after applying the SQL patch.

Comment: A SQL patch is a SP or CU.  And after any of them you have to upgrade the MDS schema.  So it does not matter what version I am running. I am trying to find a way to programmatically do this.